# How to provide custom baseURL before running fastlane command to build ad-hoc

Tags: ios, swift, fastlane, ad-hoc-distribution

I have one project with multiple Schemes, eg. DEV, PROD etc. Now i want to build ad-hoc for each Scheme and upload to firebase.

This part is done using fastlane. I defined lanes for each Scheme and then run lane commands from terminal.
Take for an example of DEV scheme,
run

> fastlane do_everything_dev

here in lane do_everything i have added,

```
desc "build and upload dev to firebase"
  lane :do_everything_dev do
      clean
      build_beta_dev
      upload_firebase_dev
  end
```

Each lane  `clean, build_beta_dev, upload_firebase_dev` have required codes to run the lane.

Now my next task is that i want to replace the baseURL in DEV scheme of my iOS app using fastlane.

Example:- If the baseURL of DEV scheme is `https://baseurl.com/{endpoint}`

I want to replace `https://baseurl.com/{endpoint}` with `https://newbaseurl.com/{endpoint}` using fastlane.

Before putting it here i searched on internet the closest i reached for my requirement is this https://docs.fastlane.tools/advanced/Fastfile/

Comment: Where have you defined the baseURL? Why would you define it in the fastlane configuration, you can define it in the scheme configuration.

Comment: baseURL is defined in EndPointsURL.swift class. I want to define it in fastlane configuration because the baseURL can be changed for a particular Scheme. 
for example- i want to build ad-hoc with different baseURL for that scheme.